Searchable drop down list in Microsoft excel
I want to create a searchable drop-down list in Excel 2016, using the filter() and search() functions, not Vlookup
I tried this formula:
=filter(A6:A368,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(E4,A6:A368)),"NOT FOUND")

I get this error:

this function is invalid


The FILTER function doesn't exist in Excel 2016, so you will your requirements in some way. You've indicated that you are looking for a formula, but you've tagged VBA. Is VBA a possibility?
